What is the impact on an index when I am widening a key varchar column
One of the central tables in my database has a varchar(25) column named EmployeeID.
This column is used within a compound index and is likely the most used index in our system.
We got an enhancement request from the business side that would require us to widen this column to varchar(75). The 200 million existing rows would not be updated and their EmployeeIDs would all still be less than 25 characters. We would just be adding a few thousand new rows that may have EmployeeIDs exceeding 25 characters.
My question is in this case, would widening the EmployeeID column have an impact on this index's performance?

Yes... but it should be minimal.  The performance of the index (time to seek to specific records) will remain approximately the same, but queries involving that index will consume more memory; but the overall impact should be fairly small.  I wouldn't worry about it.

Is there a link you could provide that would explain how the max column width impact and index's memory footprint?

It will be impacted.Index size will increase,index fragmentation will increase.But I will make some test  data then post compl;ete thing.Or you can test on these 2 points


200 million existing rows would not be updated and their EmployeeIDs would all still be less than 25 characters"


We would just be adding a few thousand new rows that may have EmployeeIDs exceeding 25 characters

Based on above statements, answer to the question:

would widening the EmployeeID column have an impact on this index's performance?

Will be that impact to index's "current" performance would be minimal / negligible, since existing records will remain the same in width - you are not going to make existing data itself wider -> so you are not going to cause index fragmentation, and not going to increase existing records in size (which would mean increase in storage space and memory consumption, hence slower querying of the index).
The index will start consuming more storage and memory over time (so querying can become slower) - compared to it's previous version - depending on how many records you add that are exceeding varchar(25) values.
